# Android with GPS and GPRS for 15 days

Tags: android, gps, battery, gprs

## Analysis

I have an [application for android phones](https://github.com/jgpATs2w/gpslibre-client-android) to collect and transmit *livestock* GPS position data to a server... At the moment I transmit the position once/10min. The battery lives for 1 day, thanks to switching to airplane mode on between connections.

To extend the **battery life**, I've increased the period between GPRS connections as much as data latency is acceptable (GPRS low coverage, lacks and animals movement makes it hard).

The user needs **15 days** of battery life, and I would like to reach it with software.

## Question

In order to collect programatically the battery usage, [I've read about the battery level](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html), but does anyone know how to monitor the *GPS* and the *GPRS modem* power consumption precisely?
At least, anyone knows how to get programatically the *Settings > Device > Battery usage* information?

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: Also, does that livestock roam a lot? Why would someone need to track a cow's movements every ten minutes? With one measure per hour you may have maybe a 4-days life for that battery. Can't you use larger batteries? Solar powered devices?

Comment: "airplane mode off between connections"??? Do you instead mean airplane mode ON between connection?

Comment: The problem is in the GPRS coverage: once/hour would be enough in theory but in practice, the data reachs the server more than two hors later. Thanks for introduce me the Super User and the tips, but i want a software solution, the animals are goats, and we do not want to increase the weight or use fragile hardware. We just want to optimize the app.

Comment: Corrected mistake, thanks @HeatfanJohn

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  Do you have Settings -> device -> battery available?  If yes, you can check that after 23 hours to see where most of the battery is being used.  You may have to run a custom Android removing unnecessary software ... or just uninstalling everything that isn't absolutely needed to run your app

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I would like to collect the from the app, and send it to server and/or store the data series locally and get stats about the battery usage. The manual approach is too uneficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the positions between longer intervals (say, four hours), but instead of connecting to the server every time you get a fix, connecting to the server only once a day, passing all the coordinates measured in the last 24 hours?

**Edit:** also while I do understand that you want some answer that's android related, every solution I have ever seen so far for tracking livestock involved stuff like transponders. If you're using cell phones, well, I can see the goats destroying the phones while trying to climb on things, or when trying to pass through a fence.